# Generación CUNE

Tags: c#, encriptación

Buen día para todos:
El problema es el siguiente estoy tratando de generar el cune para la nomina electrónica, pero ni siquiera el ejemplo que dan en la documentación concuerda, lo estoy generando en C#, si alguien me puede orientar o compartir un ejemplo se lo agradecería.

```
var cadena = "N000012020-01-161053:10-
05:003500000.001000000.002500000.007000853718001994361026931";
        var cune = "";
        using (var sha384Hash = SHA384.Create())
        {
            var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cadena);
            var hashBytes = sha384Hash.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
            var hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);

            cune= hash.ToLower();
        }
```

este es el resultado esperado:
16560dc8956122e84ffb743c817fe7d494e058a44d9ca3fa4c234c268b4f766003253fbee7ea4af9682dd
57210f3bac2
lo estoy generando en C#.

agradecería su valiosa colaboración

Comment: Y cual es el error, que es lo q te pasa?

Comment: Hola, pues que se supone que debe dar:
16560dc8956122e84ffb743c817fe7d494e058a44d9ca3fa4c234c268b4f766003253fbee7ea4af9682dd 57210f3bac2
que es lo que dice el documento de la dian para ese ejemplo pero no da ese resultado

Comment: Y como es que se calcula ese tal cune?

Comment: según el documento técnico de la DIAN se hace asi:
Composición del CUNE = SHA-384 (NumNE + FecNE + HorNE + ValDev + ValDed + ValTolNE + NitNE + DocEmp + 
TipoXML + Software-Pin +TipAmb)
Donde + significa la concatenación de las cadenas de caracteres